# The program works incorrectly fopen_s(&file, “filename”, r) in visual studio 2019 C_language

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

If you could help me, that would be much appreciated. This code is about my thesis. I'm trying to write to a file and it works but when I try to read another file it reads incorrectly. For example, the file I want to read has 5 in it, but it reads as 1. I tried to write different numbers into the file but it is constantly being read 1. Another problem is that I have to read more than one group of data in this file. That is, it will read different variables. For example, I have a data file, it will read the distance matrix first, it will read the cost matrix when it is finished. Then it will read demand array. I mean, I have to read something new on the new line. How can I do?  Help me please.

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>

 int main()
 {
     FILE* myfile;
     errno_t errorcode = fopen_s(&myfile, "output.txt", "w");

     if (myfile == NULL)
     {
        printf("Error");
     }

     FILE* data; 
     errno_t err = fopen_s(&data, "C:\\SA\\input.txt", "r");


     if(data==NULL)
     {
        printf("file does not open");
     }
     int s;
     while (!feof(data))
     {
        s = fscanf_s(data, "%d", &s);
        printf("s:%d", s);
     }
     float dist[15][15], y1, y2, x1, x2;
     dist[15][15] = sqrt(pow((y2-y1),2)+pow((x2-x1),2));

 return 0;
 getchar();
 }
```

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. `<iostream>` is not C, code also doesnt look like C++, and you say it is C,  what is it?

Comment: BTW: If you're having problems, take a break from your current code and try to reproduce and solve the issue in a [mcve], it will help you help yourself. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 comes with a builtin, very easy to use, world class debugger. You should consider having a look in to it. Invest an hour or so learning how to use it. It will save you countless hours.

Comment: Also [edit] show a minimal example of the input.txt file.

Comment: Hmm, when I compile this with Visual Studio 2019 I get 4 `uninitialized local variable used` errors.

Comment: FYI, `(x * x)` is more efficient than `pow(x, 2)`.  Also, `pow` is floating point.  Squaring a number is both integer and floating point.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding this part:

```
     while (!feof(data))
     {
        s = fscanf_s(data, "%d", &s);
        printf("s:%d", s);
     }
```

- Generally `while (!feof(data))` is [considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). You should check if readings are successful *after reading and before using what is read*.
- You assigned the return value of `fscanf_s` to the variable where the integer read is stored. This will prevent the program from using what is read. The return value of `fscanf_s` should be stored into different variable for directly checked.

It will be like this:

```
     while (fscanf_s(data, "%d", &s) == 1)
     {
        printf("s:%d", s);
     }
```

---

Regarding this part:

```
     float dist[15][15], y1, y2, x1, x2;
     dist[15][15] = sqrt(pow((y2-y1),2)+pow((x2-x1),2));
```

- The variables `y1`, `y2`, `x1`, and `x2` are used without being initialized. They have indeterminate values and using the values will invoke *undefined behavior*.
- You are assigning to `dist[15][15]`, but this is out-of-range. The number in array declaration in C are the number of elements, not the maximum index. Another *undefined behavior* is invoked.

This part looks completely nonsense and should be removed.

Comment: First of all, thank you for help. I try to this part;                                                                                                           
       while (fscanf_s(data, "%d", &s) == 1)
       {
          printf("s:%d", s);
       }                                                                                                                               
       but the same thing is happening, and it is constantly being written "1" on the screen. (although it doesn't write "1" in the file)